# Parsing non-standard XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

The following text is not valid XML, as it is using non-standard tag names and values...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Command>
    <Priority value='1'/>
    <DeviceId value='1111'/>
    <TimeOut value='30000'/>
    <Command value='GetState'/>
    <Value value='12465767890'/>
    <Number value='1'/>
    <State value='None'/>
</Command>
```

How can I parse this non-standard XML in my Java application?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: why are you using `value='1'` instead of `value="1"` ??

Comment: means by which it can be formed?

Comment: <? xml version = "1.0"?>
<sonnet type="Shakespearean">
   <author>
     <lastName> Shakespeare </ lastName>
     <firstName> William </ firstName>
     <nationality> British </ nationality>
     <yearOfBirth> 1564 </ yearOfBirth>
     <yearOfDeath> 1616 </ yearOfDeath>
   </ author>

Comment: @basvas What do you mean by 'not standard'?

Comment: here the word is used in the tag "value"

Comment: and in standard XML have an opening tag and a closing. Here only <State and /? not <State> and </State>

Comment: I need a java code which will build a similar XML

Comment: first, change ' to " second your xml is valid, third i cant say is it best for you, but i'm always using sax and it works fine for me, even for "non standard" xml

Answer (score 3):

So, what are you meaning by 'not compliant' or 'not standard'...?

*If you're meaning that its not compliant because it uses single-quotes...*

First up, I'm pretty sure that using single-quotes is already XML-compliant? However, if you want to use any standard XML-parsing libraries, you could just make the input more-compliant first, such as by replacing all `'` characters with `"` characters.

Otherwise, maybe try `extend`ing some of the components of a standard XML-parsing library, overwriting the parsing code to search for single-quotes for the attribute-value pairs.

Neither of these are very pretty, but they'll do the job.

*If you're meaning that its not compliant because the attribute-value pairs are actually called 'value' for the attribute name...*

It doesn't matter - you can call the attributes anything you want, provided it uses valid characters. Sure, it should really have a name that is meaningful, so that the XML is easier to understand, but there's nothing wrong with calling it 'value'.

The same thing goes for the tag names - there are no standard tag names for XML. XML is designed to allow you to use any tag name and attribute name that you want, as ,ong as it doesn't use any characters that aren't valid. In your case, its all English characters, so its valid.

*If you're talking about not having closing tags...*

It is valid XML to use single-tags in the form ` provided that you don't need any content to be stored in the tag. You only need opening and closing tags if you want content to be stored within it. For your tags, they're just single tags with an attribute-value pair, which is totally valid.

---

Ultimately, the best way would be to correct the input from wherever it is being generated, if possible - it isn't a very good XML-generator if it isn't writing XML-compliant output.

Comment: The problem is not in quotes, and, within the tags. I think the tags are not standard

Comment: i must named Attribute like "Priority value" ?

Comment: The tag name is `priority`. The value of the `value` attribute is `1`. You can't have spaces in tag names or attribute names.

Comment: You don't need closing tags. `<Priority value='1' />` is exactly the same as `<Priority value='1'></Priority>`, and both are valid XML.

Comment: Can write code JDOM  like                                      Element rootElement = new Element("Command");
Document doc = new Document(rootElement); ?

Answer (score 0):

In JDOM it's:

```
 Element rootElement = new Element("EivCmd");
        Document doc = new Document(rootElement);
        Element Priority = new Element("Priority");
        rootElement.addContent(Priority);
        Priority.setAttribute(new Attribute("value", "1"));
```